# Swift 3 private inheritance

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a framework and it declares a view controller.

That is all the detail that people using my framework need to know.

However, an implementation detail is that my class is based on UITableViewController.

Is it possible to publicly say that I subclass from UIViewController, but privately actually subclass from UITableViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No you can't hide you are inheriting from `UITableViewController`

If you show to someone your view controller (so you make it public) then everyone will know that it inherits from `UITableViewController`.

### has-a instead of is-a

However there is a solution. As you probably know you have full visibility control over the properties of your own class.

So you could make your `ViewController` inherit from `UIViewController` and then, inside your ViewController.swift file, define another object to control the `tableView`. Something like this

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var tableView = UITableView()
    private var tableViewController =  TableViewController()

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = tableViewController
        tableView.dataSource = tableViewController

        // add your tableView to the current view
    }
}


fileprivate class TableViewController: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        fatalError("Implement me")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        fatalError("Implement me")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes - it's perfectly possible. You just define its type as `UIViewController` in all public interfaces. Whatever methods or properties they use to access it, it is a `UIViewController` - they don't need to know the concrete subclass, or any of the super-classes (so long as one of them is eventually `UIViewController`. Since `UITableViewController` is already a subclass of `UIViewController`, so is your class that inherits from `UITableViewController`.

For example:

```
public class ControllerFactory {

    public static func createXViewController() -> UIViewController {
        return MySecretXViewController()
    }

    public static func createYViewController() -> UIViewController {
        return MySecretYViewController()
    }
}
```

They don't know or see either of the secret view controllers, but they can still get one and add it to their navigation controller or whatever. This is a pretty simple example, but in a more complex situation if you need to internally store it and do things with it, you can keep a reference to it as its proper full type:

```
var xController = MySecretXViewController()
```

And if for some reason the user needs to pass it back to you, and you need to check its type, you would do:

```
public func doSomethingWith(viewController: UIViewController) {
    if let secretX = viewController as MySecretXViewController {
        secretX.internalFunction()
    }
}
```

So from their point of view, it's just some unknown `UIViewController` subclass, they don't know its specific type, or that it inherits from `UITableViewController`. But bear in mind that all of this discussion is from an API point of view - they don't need to know implementation details/types in order to use it, but if they were to use reflection to investigate the class and its super classes, they would be able to see what it inherits from.

In summary: You can easily make it so that they don't *need* to know anything about your implementation details or types, but you can't make it *secret* in the sense that there's no way for them to find out if they really try.